# Adding the numbers 00-99 on each txt document entry

Tags: python, scripting, pycharm, python-3.8

I am building a list from scratch. I got a list offline and removed unwanted characters. Now I need to add every two digit possibility 00-99.
I am doing this as I am learning how to password crack for a pen-testing competition.
The exact thing I am trying to do is found on this website.
https://galvanizedsecurity.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/cracking-passwords/

I am a very new to python and have only done some beginner tutorials.

This is the code I used:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('SVU2.txt')]
print lines num= len(lines)
for names in lines:
     for x in range(100):
         print names.lower()+%02d%x
```

The IDE I am using is PyCharm and I am getting syntax errors at: `print lines num= len(lines)`
Also `print names.lower()`
Also `+%02d%x`

I thought the print syntax is supposed to be 'print(lines num= len(lines))'
this doesn't seem to clear the errors and I don't fully understand the code.

The author also says this is a script, am I supposed to do it a different way? Such as, not put it in the IDE?

Any help would be beneficial and I thank you seasoned and substantially smarter people than myself.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You need to refer to the existing tutorials on the Python capabilities you're trying to use.  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource.

Comment: Just for starters, that tutorial you linked is for python 2, not python 3, which is the interpreter you're running. It's admittedly not written anywhere in the blog, but you can infer this from a few things (one of which is using `print` as a statement instead of as a function `print()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) to print variable values concatenated with strings. Also, the link you're referring to is using python 2.x whereas you're using python 3.x.

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('SVU2.txt')]
print('lines num={}'.format(len(lines)))
for names in lines:
     for x in range(100):
         print(names.lower()+"{0:0=2d}".format(x))
```

Comment: This hit the nail on the head. I believe you are right, the code I was using was python 2. I have yet to learn format or that what you did with the 0:0=2d part. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use f string with python3.

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('SVU2.txt')]
print('lines num={}'.format(len(lines)))
for names in lines:
     for x in range(100):
         print(names.lower()+f'{x:02}')
```

Comment: This was close, this fixed the syntax but it labeled each word a :02 at the end of it:baggagex:02
baggagex:02
baggagex:02
baggagex:02
baggagex:02
baggagex:02
baggagex:02    it did this 100 times for each word, i'm trying to get it to cycle 00-99 without the:

Comment: f-strings use symbol : to formatted output. If use x:2 it will reserve two symbols for the x minimum, but if x low then ten, it will be filed space symbol left side to get minimum two symbols. When add zero to the format out: x:02 - it will filed not spaces but zeros.